# Text not showing up in div

Tags: html, css, block, inline, absolute

Making a slideshow from scratch, I'm trying to add text on top of each slide, the div that contains the text shows up empty but shows up fine anywhere else on the page.

[Here is the page I'm working on](http://codepen.io/YikesItsMikes/pen/MyGLGa?editors=1100)

The element I'm trying to fix is:

```
<div class="slide-title">test</div>

.slide-title{
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

I placed it 3 times on the page to test where it would show up.

Comment: It's not empty on my screen...

Comment: there's 2 red boxes, one inside the slideshow and one outside the slideshow, I'm trying to get the one inside the slideshow to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your codepen, not the code posted here, you have `font-size: 2em;`. Since you have

```
#slideshow {
    font-size: 0; /*Gets rid of horizontal space between images*/
}
```

set, this is the default font size for your child element, and so `2em` is the same as `0px`. Change one of these measures appropriately (ex. change `2em` to `20px`) and you will see the change.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked! I had tried 2em !important earlier so I thought I had covered this case.